# How to minus 1 day in date time?

Tags: mysql

I have This query which showing the id that not have from other table

```
select * from qwe where id not in (select id from ewq)
```

But i'd like to add more query inside of it that will select only the Current date - (Minus) 1 Day from the current date [Sample output of the query on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrQhG.png) 
I'd already try the query like this

```
select * 
from qwe 
where id 
and date(in_time) >= Curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY not in (select id from ewq)
```

but the output was also the same.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You have `where id 
and date(in_time) >= Curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY not in (select id from ewq)` but shouldn't that be `where id not in (select id from ewq)
and date(in_time) >= Curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`?

Comment: You got to love the loosetyped RDMS's like MySQL, pretty sure anny other RDMS which isn't loosetyped would not allow running this SQL and would error...

Comment: @Kei My bad i did'nt see that. thanks bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below query -

```
SELECT * 
FROM qwe 
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM ewq)
AND DATE(in_time) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: This solve my problem, I didn't saw that. Thanks bro.